# I can't use IMPORTXML correctly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm a beginner in Sheets, on Google.

I'm trying to import the XML from this page: `https://www.flashscore.com.br/basquete/eua/nba`

I want to get all the team's names and compare them with a game list, to see if it is the correct game. If positive, get the URL of the game on the same site.

Anyone can help me?

Just to info, I already try every way to solve this but always received N/A error. Because of that, I didn't put any formula here.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Hey, just FYI, most commercial sites purposely code their stuff in a way to prevent scraping.  It costs them money and you're not having to look at their ads.  Finding sites with scrapable content is usually just a game of guess and check.